# printing an 2d array without newline in java

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0;i< no_of_hosts;i++)
    for(int j=0;j < count;j++)
        write(Double.toString(table1[i][j]));
```

table1 has double values, and write() is printing every value as new line (in a file). 
Now I like print like this:

```
1  34  44
2  45  95
3  90  12
```

considering no_of_hosts = 3 and count = 2.
Any idea?

Comment: `write(...)` is not at fault, else you'd have ***6*** lines of result above. You likely have a println or similar functioning statement just past the statements posted, and nested in the outer for loop, at the bottom. Show a little more code, and please use the code formatting button so that it's readable.

Comment: without any more code, it's hard to say. it would be esp helpful to have the `write()` method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want an implementation of function write?

Here I have a suggestion, you should pass variable count to function write, otherwise there is no way to implement such a function only if you define the number in a line as an constant.